# Read SQLite Database from download folder and retrieve information

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am very new to android development and have some problems about application.
I have a database in **Download** folder named **database.sqlite**, this database contains name, surname, age and job.
I want my application to read database from **Download** folder and print retrieved information to text view. I want to execute query when I click on find button: `SELECT * FROM NAMES WHERE name="John" AND surname="Doe";`, Name and Surname should be got from **editText** control.

Here's my activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Name, Surname" android:id="@+id/textView" android:fontFamily="sans-serif"/>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp" android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="Name"/>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:hint="Surname"/>
<Button
        android:text="Find"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
        android:textAllCaps="false"/>
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
```

I tried other solutions from here, but failed, The database 1 GB, I use **API 25**

Thanks for attention, please help

Comment: Include your class file.

Comment: @Lokesh I have nothing in my class :(